# Python - filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, filtering

I'm new in python/django and i have a problem, i'm trying to use checkbox filtering in my html table and i don't really know how to do it.

[This is what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAChe.png)

[I want to add these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rytTy.png)

models.py

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def index(request):
    title = 'Tags'
    all_tags = Tags.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'tag/index.html' ,{'all_tags':all_tags, 'title':title})
```

How do i use filter with these, i tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
LF = 125 - 134.2 KHz
HF = 13.56 MHz
UHF = 860 - 960 MHz

LF = Tags.objects.filter(tag_frequency__gt=125, tag_frequency__lt=134.2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work` ? What is the return value of that filter query?

Comment: well more like i don't know how to make it work in template..

Comment: `Tag.frequency` is a `CharField` so you cannot expect to filter it on float values obviously. First get a working model, then it will be time to worry about "how to make it work in template"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make your query works, you have to change your field to `FloatField`:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_frequency = models.FloatField(default=0.00, null=True, blank=True)
```

Set `null`, `blank` and `default` values based on your needs.

Then, put your checkboxes (or radio inputs) in your html form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <!-- other form fields and csrf_token here -->
   <div><label for="input_lf"><input type="checkbox" name="is_lf" id="input_lf"> LF</label></div>
   <div><label for="input_hf"><input type="checkbox" name="is_hf" id="input_hf"> HF</label></div>
   <div><label for="input_uhf"><input type="checkbox" name="is_uhf" id="input_uhf"> UHF</label></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then in your view, you can try something like this:

```
def form_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # these strings come from HTML Elements' name attributes
        is_lf = request.POST.get('is_lf', None)
        is_hf = request.POST.get('is_hf', None)
        is_uhf = request.POST.get('is_uhf', None)

        # Now make your queries according to the request data
        if is_lf:
            LF = Tags.objects.filter(tag_frequency__gt=125, tag_frequency__lt=134.2)

        if is_hf:
            # another query here

        # and rest of your view
```